# Want to access "form_title_div" control in WebResource (js) in CRM 2011

Tags: dom, dynamics-crm-2011, customization, webresource

I have an Entity in CRM-2011. I want to put up a small panel in the title of this entity. I am adding a webresource javascript file inside which i am trying to access the title bar of this entity.

What i have written is `document.getElementById("form_title_div")`. However, it is returning as NULL.

How can i access this title bar of the entity for any HTML activity from webresource javascript. Please assist

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the answer you probably want - you shouldn't do this, its not supported.

> **[Do not access the DOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584(v=crm.5).aspx#BKMK_JavaScriptBestPractices)**
>
> JavaScript developers are used to interacting with Document Object Model (DOM) elements in code. You
> might use the window.getElementById method or the jQuery library. You
> are free to use these techniques in your HTML web resources, but they
> are not supported to access elements in Microsoft Dynamics CRM
> application pages or entity forms. Instead, access to entity form
> elements are exposed through the Xrm.Page object model. The Microsoft
> Dynamics CRM development team reserves the right to change how pages
> are composed, including the ID values for elements, so using the
> Xrm.Page object model protects your code from changes in how pages are
> implemented.

Comment: yes.. i accept your point.. however, in our case.. seems like we need a quick fix and doing the following wrks for mi as of now.. we will see for further upgrades.. though not particular about it -

var divTag = document.parentWindow.document.getElementById("form_title_div");